# removing noise from audio

Tags: audio, spectrogram, denoising

I have an audio file, in the range of 4 kHz to 120 kHz. I want to remove the lines that are not harmonic and are recognized as environment noise. the energy of the signal in this interval for each time bin is calculated. can I remove the noise using pitch detection?
that is also important to notice that the upper-frequency values are important and they are not noise (I should keep them).
[image]

[image]